# Crawler + Guzzle: Accessing to form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, guzzle

I am using the php guzzle Client to grab the website, and then process it with the symfony 2.1 crawler

I am trying to access a form....for example this test form here
http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/anzeige/forms_method.htm

```
$url = 'http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/anzeige/forms_method.htm';
$client = new Client($url);

$request = $client->get();
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = $request->send();
$body = $response->getBody(true);
$crawler = new Crawler($body);
$filter = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
var_dump($filter);die();
```

But i get the exception:

> The current node list is empty.

So i am kind of lost, on how to access the form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using Goutte, It is a screen scraping and web crawling library build on top of the tools that you are already using (Guzzle, Symfony2 Crawler). See the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) for more info.

Your code would look like this using Goutte

```
<?php
use Goutte\Client;

$url = 'http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/anzeige/forms_method.htm';
$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array(
    'username' => 'myuser', // assuming you are submitting a login form 
    'password' => 'P@S5'
));
var_dump($crawler->count());
echo $crawler->html();
echo $crawler->text();
```

If you really need to setup the CURL options you can do it this way:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/anzeige/forms_method.htm';
$client = new Client();
$guzzle = $client->getClient();
$guzzle->setConfig( 
    array(
        'curl.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST' => false,
        'curl.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => false,
    ));
$client->setClient($guzzle);
// ...
```

**UPDATE:**

When using the DomCrawler I often times get that same error. Most of the time is because I'm not selecting the correct element in the page, or because it doesn't exist. Try instead of using:

```
$crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
```

do the following:

```
$form = $crawler->filter('#signin_button')->form();
```

Where you are using the filter method to get the element by id if it has one `'#signin_button'` or you could also get it by class  `'.signin_button'`.
The filter method requires [The CssSelector Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html).

Also debug your form by printing out the HTML (`echo $crawler->html();`) and ensuring that you are actually on the right page.